# Handle huge amount of data in Qt

Tags: c++, qt5, qtreewidget, qlist

I need to read some text files that contain a huge amount of data, say 4 files each of about 500MB.

Each file contains several lines and each line has about this format:

```
id timestamp field1 field2 field3 field4
```

My strategy so far was to parse each file and for every line creating a QTreeWidgetItem with a suitable number of fields to store that line (this because during the program I want to show some of these data in a QTreeWidget) and appending all these items to a QList.

This QList is stored for all the execution of the program, in this way data are always available and I don't need to parse the files anymore.

I need all the data available because at each moment I need to access to data relative to a particular timestamp interval.

However this strategy seems too expansive in terms of resources, because I saw that the program consumes several GBs of memory and it eventually crashes.

How can I approach in a better way the handling of such data?

Comment: First you need to use the model-view concept (QTreeView instead of QTreeWidget). Creating a widget for millions of lines does not scale. Next you can map the files into memory and only work with pointers into the files (see `mmap()` under unix). If all that still isn't enough then you have to use the feature of the model-view concept to fill in the model as needed, scanning only those parts of the file(s) that are currently visible.

Comment: This problem of viewing large amounts of data was solved decades ago by creating a view on the large amounts of data and only load that view, and never try to load the entire data into a list control or similar (for Windows, it was called a "virtual list" control I believe).  Also as an example, sophisticated code editors are able to do this when opening large files, naive code editors would attempt to load the entire file.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Could you show me some examples of what you are talking about?

Comment: You need to manipulate the file reading to only load that part of the file you are interested in.  You don't need a huge GUI app for this.  Just a simple `main`, a very large file, and see if you can read in lines 1 to 10 into a vector, inspect you read the lines OK, clear the vector, then test reading lines maybe 60 - 80, etc.  The goal is to break the problem down -- the first issue is reading sections of an existing file into a container.  Then later, you could add cacheing to cache some portion of the file already read so that it can be immediately be loaded into the control, etc.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called 'lazy loading'.
There is an [Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtwidgets-itemviews-fetchmore-example.html) in the Qt documentation which shows you, how to use `QAbstractItemModel`, `canFetchMore()` and `fetchMore()`.